# How to make the facebook notification box that appears when someone likes or comment on our posts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Good Evening, i just want to know the name of the technology used to make the pop up box that appears when someone likes or comments on our posts and disappears after approximately 3 seconds, is it possible to make it with JavaScript or JQuery and if that is possible please could you give me an example or a link to something that demonstrates that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: @SLaks Facebook is not using serTimeout for sure! :-)

Comment: @SLaks Actually they could not use it! it's obvious that they are using some Push techniques...

Comment: @behz4d: I thought he was asking about the fade-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the appearance/ disappearance ... easy to do with `javascript`/`jquery`...

The actual notification... that comes from the server it's a push technology...

You can look for ajax push (one method is comet)

Because `HTTP` is based on request from client to server... to push something from the server to client it's a little bit more complicated... imagine everything like "this page is only to display my products but I can't show them to you only if you want to!"

Before `HTML5` this wasn't possible only with work arounds like `Ajax Push` or small `flash objects` in page that connect via `socket` to a server on a port... but now you can do it with `WebSockets`...

An `ajax push` example would be here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.jsf

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:

`Comet is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser explicitly requesting it.`

Search for `COMET`, or you could use server side JavaScript like `backbone.js` or `nod.js`

More on COMET:

```
http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29
http://cometd.org/search/node/jquery
```

More on Node.js

```
http://nodejs.org
```

And more on backbone.js

```
http://backbonejs.org
```